# Elasticsearch "put-if-absent" behavior on create doesn't seem to work

Tags: json, elasticsearch

At http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html, it says

```
Automatic ID Generation

The index operation can be executed without specifying the id. 
In such a case, an id will be generated automatically. 
In addition, the op_type will automatically be set to create. 
Here is an example (note the POST used instead of PUT):

$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/' -d '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}'
```

So based on my reading, if I run that query twice, it should only index one document, and the second one should return 409. But when I actually run it (on elasticsearch 1.3.2), it creates a document every time! What's going on, and how can I get it to index only if the document doesn't already exist, without specifying the document id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, if you don't specify an id a new guid will be generated. The create op_type means it knows it doesn't need to do an update since it has a new unique id.

You could checksum your data and set that to id, but that is a bad idea if the data every changes.